# Symfony2 / Doctrine - How to append an extra field to fetched objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, dql

## Current situation

There are four models:

### Producer

- id
- name
- description
- products (OneToMany -> Product)

### Product implements DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Taggable

- id
- name
- producer (ManyToOne -> Producer)
- tags

### Tag & Tagging

Generated by DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Taggable

## Goal

In the Producer repository, I want to get the list of producers with the tags associated to their products :

```
array(
    array( // Producer
        'id' => 1, 
        'name' => 'Producer A', 
        'description' => '...', 
        'tags' => array(
            array( // Tag
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Tag A'
            ),
            array(...)
        )
    ),
    array(...)
)
```

and I want to be able to type
    {% for tag in producer.tags %}
        {{ tag.name }}
    {% endfor %}

## Problem

I can make a SQL query like the following (which is a temporary solution) :

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'name');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('slug', 'slug');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('tags', 'tags');

    $sql = 'SELECT p.id as id, p.name as name, p.slug as slug, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.`name` ORDER BY t.`name` ASC SEPARATOR "||") as tags
        FROM `es_producer` as p
        LEFT JOIN `es_product` as pr ON pr.`producer_id` = p.id
        LEFT JOIN `es_tagging` as tt ON tt.`resource_id` = pr.id
        LEFT JOIN es_tag as t ON t.id = tt.`tag_id`
        WHERE ISNULL(p.`deleted_at`)
        GROUP BY p.id';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getArrayResult();
```

and get an array of producer's fields with an extra 'tags' field as a concanated string.

## QUESTION

- As I would like to map the fields to corresponding objects and the **tags** field does not belong to the **Producer** entity, how can I map that field to the object ?
- How can I map the **tags** as entities

Currently, I map all the fields as scalar results. Meaning that I only get an array withtout all the facilities of my objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a custom [Hydrator](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2).

Comment: Can you give more details about how to achieve this ?

Comment: The link in the answer is dead, and the link in the comment points to Doctrine1 while the question was about Doctrine2.